# Ring of Mind Shielding and ageing

Tags: dnd-5e, magic-items, dnd-adventurers-league

If you die while wearing the ring of mind shielding and choose to get sucked inside of it is there anyway of getting out of it in AL? If so, do you age while in the ring?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Well, firstly, you don't "choose" to get sucked into the ring. It just happens.

> If
>   you
>   die
>   while
>   wearing
>   the
>   ring,
>   your
>   soul
>   enters
>   it,
>   unless
>   it
>   already
>   houses
>   a
>   soul.

Secondly, you can indeed get out of it.

> You
>   can
>   remain
>   in
>   the
>   ring
>   or
>   depart
>   for
>   the
>   afterlife.

If you don't want to be trapped in a ring, then the afterlife awaits you, just as if you had died normally.

Finally, you don't age while in the ring as such. Aging is a body thing. You're a soul, the soul of a person who died. While you're in the ring, your body is rotting on the floor where you died (or in the ground, if someone gave you a decent burial).